# How to register hibernate spring entity listeners

Tags: spring, hibernate, configuration, entity, listener

I have built an entity listener but have not figured out how to register it so that it will get called.  This all runs, and I verified in the debugger that the 
registration code executes (apparently successfully) at startup.  But the debugger never stops in the listener code.

This is my listener:

```
public class DirtyAwareListener implements PostLoadEventListener
{
   @Override
   public void onPostLoad(PostLoadEvent postLoadEvent)
   {
      if (postLoadEvent.getEntity() instanceof DirtyAware)
      {
         ((DirtyAware)postLoadEvent.getEntity()).commitFields();
      }
   }
}
```

and this is the registration component:

```
@Component
public class HibernateListenerConfigurer
{
   @PersistenceUnit
   private EntityManagerFactory emf;

   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   @PostConstruct
   protected void init()
   {
      DirtyAwareListener listener = new DirtyAwareListener();
//      SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = emf.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
      EventListenerRegistry registry = ((SessionFactoryImpl)sessionFactory).getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
      registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_LOAD).appendListener(listener);
   }
}
```

Here is how my general Hibernate configuration code generates a session factory:

```
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.my.entities");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    sessionFactory.setEntityInterceptor(new DirtyAwareInterceptor());
    return sessionFactory;
```

Note that the interceptor does work as expected (but unfortunately does not have hooks where I need them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working as desired using the Integrator approach as Anton suggested.  The link provided in his answer did not provide sufficient information for me to get this to work - I had to reference multiple posts and also do a bit of trial and error.  Since I could not find a single post which provided the info, here is how I did it:

The listener code is the same as the above.  The Configurer code is not needed - I deleted it.  Here is the new Integrator code:

```
@Component
public class EventListenerIntegrator implements Integrator
{

   @Override
   public void integrate(Metadata metadata, SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactoryImplementor, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry sessionFactoryServiceRegistry)
   {
      EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry =
            sessionFactoryServiceRegistry.getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);

      DirtyAwareListener t = new DirtyAwareListener();
      eventListenerRegistry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_LOAD).appendListener(t);
   }

   @Override
   public void disintegrate(SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactoryImplementor, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry sessionFactoryServiceRegistry) {}
}
```

And here is the revised getSessionFactory method on my @Configuration class:

```
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
{
    if (sessionFactory == null)
    {
        BootstrapServiceRegistry bootstrapRegistry =
              new BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applyIntegrator(new EventListenerIntegrator())
                    .build();

        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder registryBuilder =
              new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder(bootstrapRegistry);

        registryBuilder.applySetting(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DATASOURCE, getDataSource());

        registryBuilder.applySettings(getHibernateProperties());

        StandardServiceRegistry registry = registryBuilder.build();

        MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry).addPackage("com.my.entities");
        sources.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);

        Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

        sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Note:  I think the addPackage call is not needed and does not do anything.  I had hoped it would do the package scan the old code was doing, but it does not do that.  I simply changed that to explicity add each annotated class.

Answer (score 1):

To add entity listeners implement *org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator*. See example https://www.boraji.com/hibernate-5-event-listener-example

Comment: Thanks.  I started down this path but ran into problems when trying to write the code to apply the integrator (as specified in the link you provided).  Doing so requires a different approach to implementing the getSessionFactory than the way you can see I do it, using LocalSessionFactoryBean.  When I changed, I was no longer able to get the getSessionFactory method working.  Conversely, I see no way to apply an integrator using the LocalSessionFactoryBean.  I have found examples of both the integrator approach as well as the approach I took, using the Configurer.

Comment: I am trying to add event listeners in a project where I am updating from Hibernate 3.5 to 5.6.0.Final and this is the last piece.  In following the link you provided, this told me that I had duplicate listeners in the Integrator.  I think that is because  the listeners are already defined in the hibernate.cfg.xml already.   I also have another unrelated issue when I go down this road.   So any new advice would be helpful.