# Listener on JPA PostInsert, PostUpdate, PostDelete

Tags: java, spring, jpa, events

I am trying to setup a mechanism by which changes to a particular entity trigger a notification email.  Essentially, on a PostInsert, PostUpdate, or PostDelete; an internal email address would get a notification of the event and an entity.toString().

My problem is that I cannot seem to catch the JPA events; this method, for example, never fires:

```
@Component
public class JPAEventHandler {

    @EventListener({PostUpdateEvent.class})
    public void onPostUpdateEvent(
            PostUpdateEvent postUpdateEvent) {

        System.out.println(postUpdateEvent.getEntity());
    }
}
```

I started to follow the tutorial, [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-event-listeners/), but this seems *so* heavy handed.  Is there a quicker/simpler way to catch these events?

Comment: Ofcourse that won't work. Those events aren't Spring events those are JPA events and you have to write a dedicated JPA listener not a spring event listener. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/listeners.html

Comment: My question might actually be a dupe, as this approach works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55731263/spring-boot-2-1-2-hibernate-5-register-hibernate-event-listeners-insert-updat